# Table Guava and HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, guava

I have   `Table<String,String,Doube>`and `HashMap<String,Double>`
Table `employeeYearsOfService`

```
 AT&T={Bill Smith=2.0, Stacy Lerner=1.4},
 fatima={Bill Smith=1.0, Stacy Lerner=3.0}
```

HashMap `hm1`

```
AT&T=0.962, 
fatima=0.888
```

I want calculate this and stock the result in new HashMap `hm4`

### calcul is

```
for column BIll Smith| 2.0*0.962+.0888*1.0=2.812


for column Stacy Lenner|1.4*0.962+3.0*0.888=4.0108
```

Result in my new HashMap `hm4`

```
AT&T=0.2.812
fatima=4.0108
```

### My code

I use loop for my HashMap and Table but the result is wrong

```
     Double res = 0.0;
       for (Double mapValue : hm1.values()) {
            for (String ke : employeeYearsOfService.columnKeySet()) {

              for (Entry<String, Double> employeek : 
              employeeYearsOfService.column(ke).entrySet()) {


                res+ = employeek.getValue() * mapValue.doubleValue();

           }

            hm4.put(ke, res);
        }
    }
```

Can you help me for find my error?

Comment: "the result is wrong" - in what way?

Comment: Just a guess: `hm4.put(ke, res);` - here you're _replacing_ any potential previous value while you probably want to _add_ it, i.e. look for any exisiting value, add it to `res` and then put the result into the map.

Comment: Thomas it calculat `for column BIll Smith| (2.0*0.962+1.0*0.962+2.0*0.888+1.0*0.888)` Instead of what i want

Comment: With your updated code that's no surprise. Have a look at  `res` - you're calculating _one_ value for all `ke` values. Instead you'd need to use one value per `ke` or reset `res` whenever you're operating on a new `ke` - but in that case you'd probably have to restructure your code to loop over column keys first.

Comment: Btw, this problem should be easy to solve by stepping through the code with a debugger and checking the values. That way you should be able to quickly spot where it starts to go wrong.

Comment: @Thomas 
Thank you, I will restructur my code according to your view